# Why do I get the same value when using paginate in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I just encountered this problem recently, I am using Laravel's pagination I also use ajax. If I have 2 dates that are the same, for example, I posted something today and then posted again today, when I go to the next page it just shows me the same values as the last inserted post.

**Controller:**

```
public function table() {
    $data= table::where('date_when','>=',today())->orderBy('date_when','ASC')->paginate(2);
    return view('pages.table1',compact('data'));
}
public function fetch_data(Request $request) {
    if($request->ajax()) {
        $PIData = table::where('date_when','>=',today())->orderBy('date_when','ASC')->paginate(2);
        return view('tables.table',compact('PIData'))->render();
    }
}
```

and then I use on my view `$data->links()`

Script

```
function paginateTable() {
    $(document).on('click', '.pagination a', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var page = $(this).attr('href').split('page=')[1];
        fetch_data(page);
    });

    function fetch_data(page) {
        $.ajax({
            url:"/fetch_data?page="+page,
            success:function(data) {
                $('#table_data').html(data)
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I use two views, one for displaying the table for me to use the `fetch_data` on the controller, and one for including the view which displays the table.

Comment: is the `page` value present in your request? And does your request even get sent?

Comment: yes, it just seems to return the values from the recent post, posts that have been posted the same day.

Comment: So I tried removing the `orderBy('date_when','ASC')` and it worked!. I'm confused on why it worked. I guess its because the data are already in ascending order which the `orderby asc` really wasn't able to work.

Comment: hmm I am not sure if this should have fixed the problem

Comment: I guess this is only a temporary fix

Comment: Did you check if you are getting the page parameter in controller? In the first page there is no 'page='  in the url. You can get page parameter from url after the second page

Comment: Yes I did, I might need to check on it again.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to do this.

```
$(document).on('click', '.pagination a', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var page = $(this).attr('href');
        fetch_data(page);
    });

    function fetch_data(page=null) {
        $.ajax({
            url:page?? "/fetch_data",
            success:function(data) {
                $('#table_data').html(data)
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: May I know what is the use of `url:page?? "/fetch_data"`?